# Print year range wise in php

Tags: php

```
<?php
    for($i=1990;$i<=(date('Y')-1);$i++)
    {
        for($j=1991;$j<=date('Y');$j++)
        {

        }
        echo $i.'-'.$j."<br/>";
    }
?>
```

I want to print year in range format like 1990-1991 from 1990-1991 to 2018-2019. In my code when I print range it shows me `1990-2020,1991-2020,1992-2020` like that. So, How can I print year in proper range like `1990-1991,1991-1992,1992-1993`? Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: `for($i=1990;$i<=(date('Y')-1);$i++)
    {
        echo $i.'-'.($i+1) . "<br/>";
    }` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$start =  1990;
$end = date('Y');

for( $i=$start; $i < $end; $i++ ){
    printf('%d - %d<br />',$i,$i+1);
}
```

will output:

```
1990 - 1991
1991 - 1992
1992 - 1993
1993 - 1994
1994 - 1995
1995 - 1996
1996 - 1997
1997 - 1998
1998 - 1999
1999 - 2000
2000 - 2001
2001 - 2002
2002 - 2003
2003 - 2004
2004 - 2005
2005 - 2006
2006 - 2007
2007 - 2008
2008 - 2009
2009 - 2010
2010 - 2011
2011 - 2012
2012 - 2013
2013 - 2014
2014 - 2015
2015 - 2016
2016 - 2017
2017 - 2018
2018 - 2019
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should put your `echo` inside the 2nd loop. and assign the first variable to have it's value. This should be like this.

```
    <?php
    for($i=1990;$i<=(date('Y')-1);$i++)
    {
        for($j=1991;$j<=date('Y');$j++)
        {
           echo $i.'-'.$j."<br/>";

            $i = $j;
        }

    }
?>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$start = 1999;
$end   = 2006;

for($i=$start; $i<$end; $i++)
    $ranges[] = $i . '-' . ($i+1);

print implode(', ', $ranges);
```

Output:

```
1999-2000, 2000-2001, 2001-2002, 2002-2003, 2003-2004, 2004-2005, 2005-2006
```